# Facing unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, type-mismatch

Someone to please help me solve this issue that I get on correct kotlin code.
To be precise, the issue occurs on all usages of isEmpty.

Below is the error snippet.

```
function invocation 'isEmpty(...)' expected
        return if (department.isEmpty) {
                              ^
```

I have tried downgrading and upgrading to different versions of java as well as gradle but still the issue is consistent.

Comment: please add more details , I don't think so it's having enough information to answer this question.
check isEmpty() might required instead of isEmpty property you are trying to return.

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that it's expecting a function invocation, i.e. `isEmpty()` (with the parentheses). You're treating it like a value by just doing `department.isEmpty` without the parentheses, but it has no property with that name. But it recognises it as the name of a function you can call on the `department` object, so it's telling you you need to invoke that instead.